# Android Custom shape image crop

Tags: android, crop

I want to crop the image in different shapes for that I write the XML code for that as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>               

<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/relative">

          <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="450dp"
                 android:id="@+id/original"
                 android:src="@drawable/image1"/>


          <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="450dp"
                 android:id="@+id/frame"
                 android:scaleType="matrix"
                 android:src="@drawable/f1" />

     </RelativeLayout>

       <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/btnblur"
          android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
          android:text="Crop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the layout is as shown below [output of this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdzIj.png)

And in the button click method, I wrote the code as below

Bitmap output = getBitmapOfView(frame_img);  [here frame_img is the view contains the shape]

but am getting the output as
[output on button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDoJ2.png)

so how to get the image inside the defined shape.

Comment: Before voting down,please let me know the suggestions regarding the issue.Then I will edit my questions based on your suggestions.